# In a logarithmic regression, does it matter which letter is assigned to which coefficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, regression

I have seen a logarithmic function written as:
$$y = a + b  \ln(x).$$
For example, [here](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/14059930226691).

But also, I've seen it written as:
$$ y = a \ln(x) + b .$$
For example, [here](http://support.ptc.com/help/mathcad/en/index.html#page/PTC_Mathcad_Help%2Fexample_logarithmic_regression.html%23).

Is there a reason to assign a certain letter to a certain coefficient? Does it matter which one is assigned to which?

Comment: Not that I know of, both have the same essential meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just algebraic symbols. It doesn't matter.

For familiarity, you might like to use $m$ and $c$ as $Y=mX+c$ is a common notation where $m$ represents the gradient and $c$ represents the intercept.

Hence some might prefer to write $$y=m\ln x + c$$

However, feel free to use other symbols as long as they do not cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

No, the following sets of function are equal 
$$
\{a\ln x+b\,|\,a,b\in \mathbb R\}=\{a+b\ln x\,|\,a,b\in \mathbb R\}
$$